# Не работает Primefaces после обновления до 6.1

Tags: java-ee, jsf, primefaces

После попыток победить ошибку java.lang.NoSuchMethodError при выполнении

```
<p:poll update="test" interval="5" listener="myBean.update()" />
```

путем обновления Maven репозитория( удалить упоминания primefaces  в локальном хранилище и пересобрать проект) перестали работать какие либо элементы primefaces.
Что делать ума не приложу. Прошу помоч. Дедлайнушка...

Стек ошибки

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.getComponentResources(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)Ljava/util/ArrayList;
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.DynamicResourcesPhaseListener.afterPhase(DynamicResourcesPhaseListener.java:31)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)...
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.wildpark</groupId>
    <artifactId>DSWP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>WildParkEco</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.sisu</groupId>
            <artifactId>sisu-guice</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.sisu</groupId>
            <artifactId>sisu-guice</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Сборка проходит без каких либо замечаний.
Деплой на Payara 4.1.172

Comment: Покажите pom.xml. Есть ли ошибки в процессе сборки? Как и куда деплоите?

Comment: У вас зачем-то две версии Primefaces в зависимостях. И судя по ошибке, ещё более старую версию может использовать сервер приложений. Стоит проверить содержимое каталогов `lib`.

Comment: Вторая версия - скорее из отчаянья. Каталог lib сервера приложений?

Comment: Да. Не знаю про Payara, но в Glassfish глобально используемые библиотеки лежат обычно в `glassfish\domains\<domain name>\lib\ext`.

Comment: Удалил упоминания primefaces в каталоге application/../lib. К сожалению, без результатно...

Comment: Посмотрите в своём war папку WEB-INF/lib чтобы там только один primefaces был

Comment: Удалил. Но после деплоя там появляются еще 2. Кроме необходимой версии 6.1 появляется еще 5.3 и 6.0

Comment: С какими-то другими зависимостями подтягиваются. Проверяйте все свои прожекты. Очистку прожекта делаете? Может этот мавен всё старьё в архив тащит, если не очистить предварительно перед своркой

Comment: Странно. Я c вашим pom.xml запустил `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` и получил только только primefaces-6.1.jar. Что-то ещё участвует в сборке? IDE?

Comment: Intelliji Idea используется как IDE.

Comment: Тогда стоит заглянуть в настройки проекта. Возможно, зависимость primefaces 5.3 прописана там.

Comment: А почему <p:poll update="test" interval="5" listener="myBean.update()" />
   где скобки, вот так надо:   listener="#{myBean.update()}"

Answer (score 0):

А почему

```
<p:poll update="test" interval="5" listener="myBean.update()" />
```

где скобки, вот так надо: `listener="#{myBean.update()}"`